# GridDB Error Code (PT_INVALID_NODE_ADDRESS) - Partition Table Operation Failure due to Insufficient Memory

Tags: java, griddb

I am currently grappling with an error in my GridDB implementation and would greatly appreciate your insights on resolving it.

Error Details:

Error Code: 90004
Error Message: PT_INVALID_NODE_ADDRESS
Description: Operation of the partition table failed.
This error arises during the operation of the partition table within my GridDB setup. The error explanation suggests that insufficient memory might be the root cause of the problem.

```java
try {
    GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore();
    store.dropPartitionTable("example_table");
} catch (GridStoreException e) {
    System.err.println("Error occurred while operating on the partition table: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

In response to this issue, I've conducted checks to assess the memory availability within the system. However, despite these efforts, the problem persists

I'm seeking guidance on how to effectively address the PT_INVALID_NODE_ADDRESS error. Are there any specific tools or methods I can use to diagnose memory-related issues within GridDB? Additionally, are there any best practices for optimizing memory usage to prevent such errors in the future?